# Using Maven & Jax-RS, where do I put my files?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jax-rs

I created a maven project using a Simple Web App Archetype.  Then I went in and created a Jax-RS module.  Now I have 2 index.jsp.  Should I have created my project without an archetype and then added a Jax-RS module?

I also plan to add some persistence to the project.  Maybe hibernate.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `index.jsp` for JAX-RS. Every JAX-RS servlet (Jersey, RESTeasy, etc.) provides its own `Servlet`, that dispatches REST requests into your `@Path` annotated resources. You configure the servlet in `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

The rest looks correct in your project layout.